# Create TreeNodes with key in a Linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, treeview

I am trying to create a `TreeNode` with a key, but there is no constructor for TreeNode that takes a key and a text. I found only the following solutions:

```
TreeNode tn = new TreeNode("text node");
tn.Name = "keyNode";
```

```
treeView.Nodes.Add("keyNode", "text node");
```

But those ways do not suit me, as I am trying to add new `TreeNodes` to my `treeView` with a Linq query.

---

Here is what I would like to do ideally:

```
treeView.Nodes.AddRange(
    myListOfObject.Select(x => new TreeNode(x.somePropertyForKey, 
                                            x.somePropertyForText)).
                   ToArray<TreeNodes>());
```

Am I stuck to use a `foreach` loop to create the `TreeNodes` or do you see a way to do this one-line-*ish*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thats what the new initialization syntax is for

```
TreeNode tn = new TreeNode("text node") {Name = "keynode"} ;
```

Comment: +1. It's actually called an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

Comment: I would like to see the result for this, you seem to be assigning the wrong name "tree node" first and then just overwriting the Name to "keynode", while not adding any child node at all.

Comment: The single string constructor sets the text.  Name is a separate property.  As for the Add range he is attempting to create a list of nodes to add to a single node. the object initalizer solves the issue. If thats not the goal there there is a different problem

Comment: With a `ToArray<TreeNodes>()`, I have no problem. Updated the Q.

Answer (score 1):

```
treeView.Nodes.AddRange(myListOfObject.Select(new TreeNode
               {
                  Name = "keyNode", 
                  TreeNode = new TreeNode[]{new TreeNode{Name="text node"}}}
               });
```

Should be something like that. (Please check the braces and syntax)

You would want to use this constructor [`TreeNode(String, TreeNode[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.aspx)

BTW, if that does not work and you are not hitting a database, you can do just the following:

```
treeView.Nodes.AddRange(myListOfObject.Select(new TreeNode
               (
                  "keyNode", 
                  new TreeNode[]{new TreeNode{Name="text node"}}}
               );
```